# Error with Quotation marks in Dynamic TSQL

Tags: t-sql, dynamic

I tried many posts to resolve my error below, but I am stuck. Would appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction here.

```
-- Without EXEC -- this works fine
DECLARE @BPPA AS nvarchar(5)
SET @BPPA = 'BPP2'
DECLARE @BPPB AS nvarchar(5)
SET @BPPB = 'BPP4'

SELECT T0.CustCode AS 'CustCode', MAX(T0.CustName) AS 'CustName', T0.ItemCode AS 'ItemCode', MAX(T0.ItemName) AS 'ItemName', MAX(T0.BPP) AS 'BPP',
SUM(T0.Qty) AS 'QtyP1', SUM(T0.SalesAmt) AS 'SalesAmtP1', 0 AS 'QtyP2', 0 AS 'SalesAmtP2'
FROM [dbo].[VWAJ_SALANALYSIS] T0
WHERE T0.DocDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31'
AND (
((',' + RTRIM(T0.BPP) + ',') LIKE '%,' + @BPPA + ',%') OR ((',' + RTRIM(T0.BPP) + ',') LIKE '%,' + @BPPB + ',%')
)
GROUP BY T0.CustCode, T0.ItemCode

    -- With EXEC -- Error 'Must declare the scalar variable "@BPPA"
DECLARE @BPPA AS nvarchar(5)
SET @BPPA = 'BPP2'
DECLARE @BPPB AS nvarchar(5)
SET @BPPB = 'BPP4'

EXEC('
SELECT T0.CustCode AS ''CustCode'', MAX(T0.CustName) AS ''CustName'', T0.ItemCode AS ''ItemCode'', MAX(T0.ItemName) AS ''ItemName'', MAX(T0.BPP) AS ''BPP'',
SUM(T0.Qty) AS ''QtyP1'', SUM(T0.SalesAmt) AS ''SalesAmtP1'', 0 AS ''QtyP2'', 0 AS ''SalesAmtP2''
FROM [dbo].[VWAJ_SALANALYSIS] T0
WHERE T0.DocDate BETWEEN ''2016-01-01'' AND ''2016-03-31''
AND (
(('','' + RTRIM(T0.BPP) + '','') LIKE ''%,'' + @BPPA + '',%'') OR (('','' + RTRIM(T0.BPP) + '','') LIKE ''%,'' + @BPPB + '',%'')
)
GROUP BY T0.CustCode, T0.ItemCode
')
```

What am I doing wrong? I believe I am missing some quotation marks, but not sure how many and why.
Thanks in advance!
AJ

Comment: You should be using parameters to pass values to `execute` in order to avoid, among other things, [SQL injection](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/raulga/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you could have read the error message, that should have given you a hint.

The quotation marks look ok, the main problem is that the scope for variables is the batch they are declared in. The `EXEC` statement executes the sql string in a separate batch, so your variables `@BPPA` and `@BPPB` can't be found in that batch. You have to split your string to take the values from the calling batch:

```
DECLARE @BPPA AS varchar(5) = 'BPP2'
DECLARE @BPPB AS varchar(5) = 'BPP4'

EXEC('
SELECT T0.CustCode AS ''CustCode'', MAX(T0.CustName) AS ''CustName'', T0.ItemCode AS ''ItemCode'', MAX(T0.ItemName) AS ''ItemName'', MAX(T0.BPP) AS ''BPP'',
SUM(T0.Qty) AS ''QtyP1'', SUM(T0.SalesAmt) AS ''SalesAmtP1'', 0 AS ''QtyP2'', 0 AS ''SalesAmtP2''
FROM [dbo].[VWAJ_SALANALYSIS] T0
WHERE T0.DocDate BETWEEN ''2016-01-01'' AND ''2016-03-31''
AND (
(('','' + RTRIM(T0.BPP) + '','') LIKE ''%,''' + @BPPA + ''',%'') OR (('','' + RTRIM(T0.BPP) + '','') LIKE ''%,''' + @BPPB + ''',%'')
)
GROUP BY T0.CustCode, T0.ItemCode
')
```

For the passing of parameters, you should have a look at the system stored procedure [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql).

**Example added:**
Using `sp_executesql`, your EXEC statement could look like this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'
SELECT T0.CustCode AS ''CustCode'', MAX(T0.CustName) AS ''CustName'', T0.ItemCode AS ''ItemCode'', MAX(T0.ItemName) AS ''ItemName'', MAX(T0.BPP) AS ''BPP'',
SUM(T0.Qty) AS ''QtyP1'', SUM(T0.SalesAmt) AS ''SalesAmtP1'', 0 AS ''QtyP2'', 0 AS ''SalesAmtP2''
FROM [dbo].[VWAJ_SALANALYSIS] T0
WHERE T0.DocDate BETWEEN ''2016-01-01'' AND ''2016-03-31''
AND (
(('','' + RTRIM(T0.BPP) + '','') LIKE ''%,'' + @BPPA + '',%'') OR (('','' + RTRIM(T0.BPP) + '','') LIKE ''%,'' + @BPPB + '',%'')
)
GROUP BY T0.CustCode, T0.ItemCode
'
, N'@BPPA nvarchar(5), @BPPB nvarchar(5)'
, @BPPA = N'BPP2', @BPPB = N'BPP4'
```

Instead of the constants, you can also pass the values from your variables like this (replacing the last line of my sample script):

```
, @BPPA = @BPPA, @BPPB = @BPPB
```

Comment: Hi, Tried to add sp_executesql with 2 parameters, but got same error. Would appreciate it very much if you could guide me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try this code below. I don't have for right now any access to SQL Server :)

```
DECLARE @BPPA AS nvarchar(5)

SET @BPPA = '''%,BPP2,%'''

DECLARE @BPPB AS nvarchar(5) 

SET @BPPB = '''%,BPP4,%'''

DECLARE @sSQL  AS varchar(750)

SET @sSQL = 'SELECT T0.CustCode AS ''CustCode'', MAX(T0.CustName) AS ''CustName'', T0.ItemCode AS ''ItemCode'', MAX(T0.ItemName) AS ''ItemName'', MAX(T0.BPP) AS ''BPP'', SUM(T0.Qty) AS ''QtyP1'', SUM(T0.SalesAmt) AS ''SalesAmtP1'', 0 AS ''QtyP2'', 0 AS ''SalesAmtP2'' FROM [dbo].[VWAJ_SALANALYSIS] T0 WHERE T0.DocDate BETWEEN ''2016-01-01'' AND ''2016-03-31'' AND ( (('',''' + RTRIM(T0.BPP) + ''','') LIKE  N' + @BPPA + ') OR (('',''' + RTRIM(T0.BPP) + ''','') LIKE N' + @BPPB + ') ) GROUP BY T0.CustCode, T0.ItemCode ')

EXEC (@sSQL)
```

Hope this can help you